# Apostrophes and imagettftext()

Tags: php, imagettftext

I've been trying forever to figure out what's going on here. I'm trying to use imagettftext() to put text on an image I'm creating in PHP. I've got some text:

```
$line = "I'm using this string";
```

When I echo is out it displays exactly the same. The final imagettftext() variable is the line that places the text on the image. So when I do this:

```
echo $line."</br>";

imagettftext($my_img, $font_size, 0, $x+4, (($font_size+$margin_top)*$line_number)+$new_shadow_addition, $shadow_colour, $font, $line);
```

It echoes out the line correctly but then when I look at the image, it displays it as

```
I□m using this string
```

And it does so for any other apostrophe. The string is correct but it somehow encodes it or decodes it before imagettftext(). I tried to convert it to pure UTF-8 before using imagettftext but it still didn't matter (it's currently in ASCII; I detected the encoding before I used it).

It's not the font I'm using because I've tried several fonts.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

### EDIT

For further information, I'm using simple_html_dom to crawl data from another page and then using that info for the image so I'm not sure if that would affect anything. It shouldn't because I've detected the encoding and the characters and nothing seems out of place.

This is driving me absolutely crazy, I've been revisiting this for three days now and it doesn't make sense. I've tried all UTF-8 decoding possibilities in PHP and anything else I can think of or find. I did a rawurlencode() on the string that I'm using and it's returning a `%92` for the apostrophe character meaning it is an apostrophe, not a single quote or the `%60` character. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

### EDIT

I've determined that this is just related to the apostrophe character (%92 in ASCII). I've tried with %27 (the single quote) and that works fine. No other character I've seen seems to cause the problem either so it looks like it's isolated to the apostrophe character.

Comment: Did you see these questions? [GD rendered image not displaying apostrophes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892204/gd-rendered-image-not-displaying-apostrophes), [PHP GD Text and Special Characters / Encoding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054160/php-gd-text-and-special-characters-encoding)

Comment: Yes, I've tried html_entity_decode() and trim() on the text and that's not working either...

Comment: yeah i miissed that font statment,my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know WHY it was happening but I figured out a workaround in case anyone else has this problem (and if so, I feel your pain, super frustrating...).

I did this:

```
$line = rawurlencode($line);
$line = str_replace('%92', '%27', $line);
$line = rawurldecode($line);
```

It url encodes it, finds the apostrophe characters (%92) and replaces them with a single quote character (%27). This is not exactly an answer to the question but it's a solution to the problem. Hope this helps someone.